# Remove AHREF next Html tag

Tags: html, wordpress, css

```
</body>
</html>
<a href="http://example.com">visit us</a>
```

I have wordpress theme with this ahref in ALL pages, can i remove??. I search on all php functions and css style but nothing...any idea?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: CSS cannot remove content, it can only HIDE it.

Comment: did you look in the database? wordpress stores most everything content-related in the DB.

Comment: This is most probably located in your top template or whatever it is called in WordPress. Can't you just download the files and look for "</html>" so that you can identify which file this template is ?

Comment: And it's outside the closing html tag? Hmmm. Anyway, you could also use JavaScript to remove it.

Comment: Your site is probably infected, and the link may point to a malware site. I'm not sure about including files/code, but often `.htaccess` file is used to infect sites -- check `.htaccess` file in your site's root directory for suspicious code.

Comment: i see htaccess but nothing

Comment: finally hide on footer.php.....thanks for your attention and time

Comment: If your site is infected and the link points to a malware site, then removing it with JS is not enough. Your site is still at risk of being banned by search engines and blocked by antivirus software. I would recommend to search for HTML code of this suspicious link in your HTML templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS cannot remove element from DOM. If you know javascript or better jQuery, just give all anchor which you want to remove a specific class then remove it all by using:

```
$(".yourClass").remove();
```

If you don't know jQuery, then you need to use the parent of each element to remove it:

```
element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Comment: thanks for your time guys!, but I don´t know what´s the problem. I see the same link in all pages.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have this tag in footer template, scroll down to check if there is any text written after closing html tag, or sometimes the case may be that your editor does not have wrap text option set as  a result you are not able to see this text may be on right side, scroll to right of the editor or alternatively you can use the search option to locate the text.